# Combining more than 20 raster bands in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, combine

I have overlapping polygon data that I would like to 'combine' in ArcGIS and I'm running up against the 20 band maximum for rasters.

I'm interested in solutions using this basic method with ArcGIS Desktop.

I have many overlapping polygons 300+ that represent ranges of animals within a large area 100,000+ Acres.  I have many unique attributes for each polygon representing various characteristics for the individual.  I also have 30m categorical raster data for vegetation, ownership, and several other layers.    I attempted to look at this by trying to split up the feature class (.shp file) with the 300+ polys into individual files then convert feature -> raster,  then obviously I run into the issue of too many

I'm beginning to think it would be easier to convert the raster layers (vegetation and ownership e.g.) raster - > polygon and then use the cross tabulation tool.

Comment: You can use Union with polygon layers, this will give you all the attributes from the input feature classes.. to keep it simple then remove the fields that don't matter (like FID_1, Shape_Area1...) until you have a table of all your polygons with 0 or Null in a field where there is no overlap - depending on whether your output feature class supports Null.

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @MichaelStimson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150204/combining-more-than-20-raster-bands-in-arcgis-desktop/250589#comment220061_150204):

> You can use Union with polygon layers, this will give you all the
>   attributes from the input feature classes.. to keep it simple then
>   remove the fields that don't matter (like FID_1, Shape_Area1...) until
>   you have a table of all your polygons with 0 or Null in a field where
>   there is no overlap - depending on whether your output feature class
>   supports Null.